# Windows Vista freezes after 2-3 minutes

Tags: windows-vista, freeze

After Vista has been running in normal mode for 2-3 minutes (regardless of whether I log in) it freezes up and all I can do is move the mouse around. This doesn't occur in safe mode or running Ubuntu. I have a T400 so I've tried both graphics cards and that hasn't made a difference. I have a hunch the problem is related to Explorer in normal mode, but I could be entirely off base.

Also, when using system restore in safe mode, it BSODs after starting the process.

The only Windows Update I made that day was a Defender definition update. The actual problem started when I was running [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/). About 2/3 through my OS froze up, so without thinking I just yanked the battery out and put it back in, and that's when things went downhill. I've since uninstalled it, but that didn't do anything (not that I expected it to). It might be related but it could have just been a coincidence.

I'm open to pretty much any ideas for troubleshooting, or I can post more information if anything would help. At worst, I do have a free Windows 7 upgrade I could try, but I'd rather that be a last resort.

Comment: install Windows 7 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Some ideas:*

A problem with Explorer in Normal Mode could be it, but that sounds like a virus. Also, perhaps you *should* try Windows Update. Lately I've seen a few nasty rootkits floating around... (I don't mean to scare ya' - just saying)

Can you please give some more info about your specs? I am not sure what a T400 is... (I can Google it, but...)
Also, perhaps you can clarify a little: Does Safe mode work now or not?

Finally, perhaps the Windows 7 Upgrade is the best option regardless of Vista freezing up...

EDIT:

Try manually downloading SP2 from Microsoft.com. Also, Have you run a virus scan yet? If not,  recommend a few programs...

- AVG Free 9
- OR MalwareBytes
- OR Avira
- OR Avast
- Trend Micro House Call (An internet based virus scanner)

And

- SpyBot Search & Destroy : For Adware(Be careful of some of the mirrors' download page,lots of ads, hard to discern the real link)
- Lavasoft Ad-Aware

They say not to use multiple Anti-Virus side-by-side, but I've been ok with it.
Also, if all else fails - system restore will possibly help.

** EDIT 2: **

Also, look at the System Event Viewer in the control panel under Administrative tools). Perhaps there is some indication of error or failure in WinDirStat...

**Edit 3:**

If System Restore is causing the BSOD, try a different restore point. It may not b a virus after all. (Leaving the info up as reference, though.)

Comment: I've already run everything in Windows Update. I think I'm using SP1.. Windows Update never prompted me for SP2, so I'm not sure whether it's a recommended upgrade or what.


The T400 is just a recent Lenovo Thinkpad laptop. It supports switching between an onboard Intel graphics card and a discrete Radeon one. Safe mode definitely does work, as does Ubuntu.


If I do upgrade to Windows 7, I'd much rather do it at my leisure :) (Sorry for the lack of linebreaks, they're not being parsed.)

Comment: @whichdan - Line breaks are forgiven. I have never had success with them here on SU. ;)

Comment: Also, System Restore is what was causing the BSOD. Couldn't think of the name.

Comment: I tried a few restore points with no success. I'll try downloading SP2.

Comment: SP2 didn't work, but that error led me to try a chkdsk, and that fixed the problem! A few bad files were removed and everything seems fine.

Comment: Good to hear that you fixed the problem. I should've suggested chkdsk... Often when the machine hangs mid-process, that is the first answer. (If it won't boot the next step is fixboot or fixmbr.)  Congrats.